# Read text file to a list and assign it to a class attributes

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class which reads from a text file and it assigns to sub classes and its giving me:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

and I don't get it all,the constructor at super class employee is like this:

```java
public Employee(String employeeId, String fname, String lname, String dateOfBirth, String gender, String address, String titleOfEmployment, String dateHired, String department, double hoursWorked, double rateOfPay, String leaveDays, double carAllowance, double salary, double taxRate) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.address = address;
    this.titleOfEmployment = titleOfEmployment;
    this.dateHired = dateHired;
    this.department = department;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.rateOfPay = rateOfPay;
    this.leaveDays = leaveDays;
    this.carAllowance = carAllowance;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
}
```

and here is the class for reading the file:

```java
public class Freader {

    // ** Reads the file one line at a time. Each line will is that split up and translated into a Passenger object */
    public static List < Employee > readline() throws IOException {
        List < Employee > employee = new ArrayList < > ();

        String file = "employees.txt";
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        String line;

        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

            Employee emp = new Employee(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[5], tokens[6], tokens[7], tokens[8], Double.parseDouble(tokens[9]), Double.parseDouble(tokens[10]), tokens[11],  Double.parseDouble(tokens[12]), Double.parseDouble(tokens[13]), 
 Double.parseDouble(tokens[14]));

            emp.setEmployeeId(tokens[0].trim());
            emp.setFname(tokens[1].trim());
            emp.setLname(tokens[2].trim());
            emp.setDateOfBirth(tokens[3].trim());
            emp.setGender(tokens[4].trim());
            emp.setAddress(tokens[5].trim());
            emp.setTitleOfEmployment(tokens[6].trim());
            emp.setDateHired(tokens[7].trim());
            emp.setDepartment(tokens[8]);
            emp.setHoursWorked(Double.parseDouble(tokens[9]));
            emp.setRateOfPay(Double.parseDouble(tokens[10]));
            emp.setLeaveDays(tokens[11].trim());
            emp.setCarAllowance(Double.parseDouble(tokens[12]));
            emp.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(tokens[13]));
            emp.setTaxRate(Double.parseDouble(tokens[14]));

            employee.add(emp);

        }
        return employee;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should check if the line if empty or not before you start to use the tokens array. You can also read the full stack trace to know where you fail

Comment: Can you provide the file too please?

Comment: here is the contents of the file:** too,dt,ft,13/03/00,male,kanye,IT, 13/03/00,records,5.3,6.0,12days,50.0,70.0,12.0
gg,hj,ht,12/09/00,female,gabs,HR,12/09/00,Sales,45.5,8.0,12days,9.9,9.5,90.6**

Answer (score 1):

From the comment, it looks like data is separated by comma(,) and in the code it is done through space. So obviously will fail.

Instead of

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
```

should be

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
```